# How to traverse/rebuild UIComponent tree structure in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, tree, traversal

I have some kind of UIComponent grouping which may look something like this with the classes "Group" and "Element".

Groups can have children and children may be elements or groups again, basically similar to a file system or the str+g group function in several graphics programs. The simplest form of a group is a group with only children which are also the most low level groups in the tree.

Edit:
The display hierarchy is already existant, i try to persist it to xml.

```
Group
   - element
   - Group
      - element
      - Group
         -element
         -element
   - element
   - element
```

I want to rebuild this structure in an xml-document for persistence.
I know how to build an xml document in Flex but not how to (recursively) traverse this n-tree correctly.

**Update:**

For getting only the child nodes one could make use of the following algorithm (pseudo code). But somehow i don't understand how to create the xml from this.

```
 walkTree(group) {
        children = node.getChildren
        if(children != null) {
            for(int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                if(children[i].isGroup()) {
                    walkTree(group[i]);
                } else {
                        trace(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused; Are you trying to traverse an already created display hierarchy; or are you trying to create the hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry for confusion.
The display hierarchy is already existant. I try to persist this hierarchy to xml.

Comment: Why would you care about persisting?  So you can re-create it later?  Or for some other reason?  It is highly unusual to try to create a display hierarchy "On The fly" at runtime.  This question touches on a lot of topics.  IF you need help converting your algorithm to ActionScript, we can help with that.  If you need help parsing XML and creating display objects, we can help with that but you'll have to show us your XML.  If you need help defining your XML schema; this may not be the best forum to ask. If you need help w/ all three, you should hire a consultant.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, I'd suggest this : http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/E4X/

So, basically, what you are looking for seems like E4X in Actionscript 3

Comment: I've read your post many times and traversal is exactly what E4X does for you. If you need to write your own recursive function, you already have the pseudocode (maybe you're asking the Actionscript translation of that). However, you're not very clear about what exactly you're asking and I agree with Flextras on this matter.

I don't know your background and I don't know your long term goal with this problem but if you can present us the big picture, we might a better and more elegant solution than writing recursive functions because this is pretty much already done for you in Flex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894522/flex-actionscript-loop-through-xml-find-if-at-least-one-checked/3895780#3895780

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have your structure be data driven from the start, so the XML controls the draw of the screen.  Then you would have the XML and wouldn't need to make it.

However, if you really want to do this, you'll need to loop through all the children at each level and add some sort of node that describes the child.  However, if you don't have a view that is data driven, I don't see what good this will do you (and if you do, and it's not XML, you're better off writing data export from the data side, not the view side).